# Lisp language beginner details

Tags: lisp, artificial-intelligence

I wish to learn Lisp as I am going towards Artificial Intelligence (AI).  Can somebody share some good book names of tutorials which covers good amount of Lisp details?

Just googling it, but didn't find anything good which covers the language in detail.

Also, which software is required for programming (like for .NET languages we usually use Visual Studio to do programming)?

Thanks in advance.

Thank you all for the helpful responses... :)

Answer (score 5):

### [Paradigms of AI](http://norvig.com/paip.html)

Really good for learning Lisp, but especially if you're aiming for AI. It covers a lot of the techniques that you'll need and shows how to use them.

Answer (score 4):

In your googling did you see [*Practical Common Lisp*](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/)? It's a great starting point.

One caveat about PCL is that it starts out with the most obsolete kinds of constructs, explaining how to create global variables, using property-lists, etc., I was surprised by how it began with all this really gnarly old stuff that had nothing to do with what I wanted to learn. Eventually it does get around to very lucid explanations of macros and multimethods and stuff, so it does get better if you stick with it. But if you want to get into Lisp but skip the nasty old cruft, my advice is go straight to learning Clojure, which is a very recent Lisp built with the idea of supporting modern programmers' needs.

Introductory resources for Clojure:

1) [Rich Hickey's presentation "Clojure for Java Programmers"](http://blip.tv/file/982823), which gives a good overall idea of what Clojure is about.

2) Stuart Halloway's *Programming Clojure*, which is a good introduction to the language.

3) Fogus and Houser's *Joy of Clojure* covers more advanced material you'd otherwise have to find by rummaging through a lot of books on Common Lisp and Scheme and sorting out which bits are relevant and which are outdated.

As for software Lisp people (including those using Clojure) tend to use Emacs a lot. However, you can use vi (there's a paren-matching option that comes in handy) and Eclipse has plugins you can use (Cusp for Common Lisp, Counterclockwise for Clojure).

Answer (score 2):

ANSI Common Lisp, Paul Graham is the bible of Lisp, my opinion.
LispWorks is the most commonly used (GUI) IDE (like Visual Studio) to
develop, test, debug, compile your Lisp projects.  It is a commercial
product but for individual usage is for free on Linux, Windows and
even Mac OS X.  I prefer to use Emacs (nox version) & CLisp on my
Ubuntu OS.  I love my console. 8-)

Comment: I think that Emacs+Slime is more common than LispWorks, but that may just be the people I know.

Answer (score 0):

Any text editor will do the job of editing source code--even Windows' Notepad.  However, given that Lisp code will have nested parentheses, you will likely want an editor which will help you match open and close parentheses, such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (or if you're a little more Unix-centric, emacs or vim).

I've never gotten more serious about Lisp programming to go beyond using GNU clisp or the Lisp interpreter in emacs for small projects, so I can't really recommend anything more sophisticated.  However, this [list of Lisp References](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/Lisp-Notes/Lisp-References.html) looks like a good starting point for potential reading material.

Comment: I've written Lisp, or tried to, with an editor that wasn't parenthesis-aware.  I really, really don't recommend it.

Comment: I highly don't recommend editors that can't auto-indent Lisp code. Parentheses matching is NOT sufficient unless you like pain.

Comment: Who doesn't like pain?  I used to use Notepad to crank out Lisp applications.  No problem - until there was.  Better to use a totally configurable editor that you like.  Emacs was just the first ...

Answer (score 0):

The classic text for AI & Lisp is the Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming ([PAIP](http://norvig.com/paip.html)).

On Lisp is a pretty good text as well.

I use emacs + Slime for my Common Lisp work; it's not the most modern, but works quite well. I have never yet felt the need for a commercial Lisp IDE. Others may disagree.

Answer (score 0):

And if you are interested in learning how to program games with Lisp, you can also check [Land of Lisp](http://landoflisp.com/)